# Distributing indexes of a large file over several computers

Tags: java, distributed

I want to distribute the processing of a large file (almost 1GB) over many machines. One option would be to store the whole file in all the machines and pass indexes from the master machine. But I not able to understand how I must do this in Java. I want to do this mainly for optimization. More specifically, I want each machine to process a different part of the file and return the result. The problem is that the file reading cannot start from a specific line, so on each machine the file would have to be read from the beginning, which will waste the time as the processing is being done several times. Can there be any solution for this?

Comment: It sounds like what what you want is Hadoop.   But are you sure you need to do this? 1GB is not a large file

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The size is not that big.But the file has to be run over many many times. So, I thought of distributing the processing over many machines. Is there a simpler alternative than Hadoop?

Comment: What is it you're doing with the file?

Comment: Im not doing any modifications to the file. Im reading it and comparing the values of each line with a vector and then calculating a value based on that. But, this has to be done many times. Im using it in a genetic algorithm and the file has to be read for each chromosome.

Comment: Read the file just once to save on I/O costs and read it only from memory.  If you have multiple cores, split the work up among threads.  Unless your work is massively CPU intensive I doubt you'll get any speed up splitting the work over multiple machines.  The Fork/Join framework will probably help you